# iOS 11 autocorrect bug typing the letter capital I

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization

So for some odd reason it seems that some iPhones are having trouble processing the letter "I" and I was wondering if anyone knows the solution to this or if it's just a bug in iOS 11?

on some iOS 10 and iOS 11 devices, a question mark shows up or another symbol where they should be an I. Examples:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: iMessage autofill]

Comment: There are several reports on this in the Apple Support Communities with no cause or fix identified.  Could you copy/paste the sequence here?  I think the question mark may be the FE0F unicode variation selector, which is used with some emoji in certain circumstances.

Comment: This is happening to me too! Whenever I type the letter “I” in Snapchat or, instagram, the symbol pops up as a question mark (as seen above). I️ just tried typing the letter and that symbol also just appeared. I️ (Appears when the letter “I” is typed)

Comment: The extra symbol is in fact U+FE0F.  No idea what would make it appear there.

Comment: Had this issue as well. Resetting keyboard settings didn’t fix it, but erasing the phone did.  Restoring from backup after erase doesn’t appear have caused the problem to come back.  Filed a bug report with Apple: rdar://35306062

Comment: This solution using text replacement doesn’t work for me. It says the phrase cannot contain any emoji

Comment: @Elliott Try putting in just i and not the copy/pasted stuff.

Comment: @TomGewecke I tried that, but no replacement happens

Answer (score 11):

This is described by Apple:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208240

I think this must be a bug in the system for suggesting emoji in Predictive Text.  The mystery character is FE0F, Unicode [Variation Selector-16](https://emojipedia.org/variation-selector-16/), which is used to signal that the preceding character should have emoji instead of text presentation format.

Solutions / Workarounds:

- turn off predictive text
- use a 3rd party keyboard
- Settings > General > Keyboard > Text Replacement

Set up a text replacement small i to capital I.

Apple has now issued [similar advice](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208240).

Many people are waiting for an iOS update, but you could try backing up your device and erasing all content and settings and then restoring your backup. That should fix the issue for you at the cost of making sure your backup is encrypted and has health data and all apps are still available for redownload.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11.1.1 just got released and its supposed to fix this problem:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208067
- https://www.theverge.com/2017/11/9/16629434/apple-ios-11-update-autocorrect-i-problem-fix-iphone

**Edit:** Oh my god, what a shame. If they would have waited just a little longer, they would have released version 11.1.1 on the 11/11...!!!